# Can we burninate isqlquery?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[isqlquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isqlquery)

Only 40 questions. Only 7 of which have the tag [nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate).

I added a tag excerpt, but then I realized I do not see the need for this tag at all. Most of the questions on the site about ISQLQuery are not even tagged with this tag. [nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate) should suffice, but I am no C# expert.

Question to C# SMEs: Do we need this tag or can we burninate?

Answer (score 4):

It's a relevant keyword for problems on this topic and (according to quick googling) not ambiguous (the only alternative is [an abandoned Java library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/isqllibrary/files/)) i.e. a valid tag name.

So I reckon it should be a synonym to [nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate).